# Python list and dictionary and fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I need to check if item of list in MySQL db model exists in fastapi request. For example, if cred is list stored in model which has some items if fastapi request is null then I want JSON response as that field is mandatory in request.

If cred contains username, password, port and fastapi post request has empty password then message should be displayed as password required.

I want it dynamic as cred item may be changed later on `your text`.

```py
cred=['port','username','password']

request={"username":"abc",
"port"   :"3306"}
for i in range len(cred):
 if "username" in cred[i]:
   if request.username=="":
      return JSON response({"data":"username required"})
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't write that as a Pydantic model and use the regular validation in FastAPI? Are the values dynamic _per request_, or what does "may be changed later" mean? If it's statically defined in your code (i.e. the code changes), use a pydantic model that describes what a valid request looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Make them both sets, and compare the sets:

```
cred=['port','username','password']
request={
    "username":"abc",
    "port":"3306"
}

request = {k:v for k, v in request.items() if v and k in cred}
diff = set(cred) - set(request)

if diff:
    response = {"data": f"{', '.join(diff)} required"}

print(response)
```

Output:

```
{'data': 'password required'}
```

Comment: Yes it's correct Thanks , but one issue can you plz help..if password key is there in request but value is empty as "" still it should give password required...how can I do it

Comment: Try something like: `if not request.get("password", True): del request["password"]`

Comment: Added the line `request = {k:v for k, v in request.items() if v and k in cred}`. `if v` means values must be truthy, and `if k in cred` means the keys must be in your `cred` list.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the `password` key first of all, I would write:

```py
if not request.get("password", True):
    del request["password"]
```

This `.get()` call returns `True` if the item is not found, because of the `not` it evaluates to `False`.

If it is found, it will return the value of `request["password"]`. Since empty strings evaluate to `False` in python, it will be inverted again and run the `if` statement, deleting the value.

Lastly, to find all the items in `cred` that don't appear in `request`. As @BeRT2me answered, convert both data types to sets, and compare them.

To add on to it, if the password key is valid, `diff` will become an empty set. Which will evaluate to `False`.